# Avoid using localhost to resolve tests in mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, supertest

For some reason when I set my app in `test.js` like this:

`const app = express();`

I get a 404 error for all tests.

However, when I set it like this

`const app = 'http://localhost:3000'`

all tests pass.

I'm aware though that this is not the best way to declare `app` in a testing environment. how can I avoid using a fix path like localhost ?

example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// const app = 'http://localhost:3000'
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const request = require('supertest');

  it('For all bookings', function (done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/bookings')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        expect(res.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
```

that way I get `Uncaught AssertionError: expected 404 to equal 200`

but if I uncomment `const app = 'http://localhost:3000'` to use it instead of `const app = express();` then the test passes.

Comment: Please add some code-examples to help reproducing this bug. Thanks!

Comment: @lo1c just did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const app = express()` creates dummy Express instance with no routes. It cannot respond to a request to `/bookings` endpoint because there's no such endpoint.

That `http://localhost:3000` works means that an application that has has `/bookings` route is currently running.

In case application instance is provided to Supertest's `request`, an instance of the application that has `/bookings` route should be imported:

```
const app = require('./app');
```

Comment: It works now, but I get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Does the error not occur in production for the same request? The problem is likely specific to the app, not to Supertest. The error usually means that you sent a response twice.

Answer (score 1):

if we did this in the test file

```
const app = express();
```

it means that we create brand new express application with no routes defined. The correct way is to use same express application not create a new one.

In order to do that, we can export the express app and refer it from the test file.

```
// index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/bookings', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

module.exports = app; // export express app
```

Meanwhile for test file

```
// test.js

...

const app = require("./index"); // import the app

it("For all bookings", function(done) {
  request(app)
    .get("/bookings")
    .end(function(err, res) {
      console.log(res);
      expect("Content-Type", /json/);
      expect(res.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
      done();
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works now, but I get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: you may need to check the code in source file whether you send response more than once.